# why check validity only after doing a defensive copy?

Tags: java

Please note this code:

```
public Period(Date start, Date end) {
 this.start = new Date(start.getTime());
 this.end = new Date(end.getTime());
 if (this.start.compareTo(this.end) > 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(start +" after "+ end);
```

}

I do not see how it matters if the check for validity of parameters(ie the call to `compareTo()`) is done before defensively copying the mutable parameters to the constructor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a concurrent environment, `start.getTime()` and `end.getTime()` could change anywhere in the middle of that constructor.

In particular, if the check were done first, you could have inputs that passed the check, and then another thread modifies them with invalid values, and then the defensive copy copies the invalid values.  Result: armageddon.

It's not exactly likely, or that big an issue, but it makes sense to err on the side of caution -- that is, after all, why it's called defensive programming.

Comment: how can start.getTime() and end.getTime() change ever in the middle of a constructor ? start and end are private final variables and the class is not exposing their internals by doing the defensive copy here

Comment: `start` and `end` are constructor arguments, passed in by untrusted code.  Anyone could have a reference to them, and do evil things with them.  That's why we do the defensive copy _first_.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see your point . This is also why  doing the checking on copy makes sense ?

Comment: There are two aspects to this answer. One is that `java.util.Date` is mutable, so you *must* copy it at some point. Absolutely true. The second is that it could get modified by some concurrent thread. So the copy up front makes sense. But note that `Date` does not provide thread safety for `getTime()`, so while this will produce consistent results, it still won't save you from foolish use. Note in particular that with Java, `long` member variables can be more than just out of date, they can be corrupt in incorrect multi-threaded use.

Comment: Hah, point taken.  But there's no way to "get thread safety back," or to impose it yourself, so I suppose this is the best approximation possible.